Why does my newly created phantom wallet not show up on solana explorer?
i created a new solana wallet using phantom.
But when i go to view that address in solana explorer the balance tab shows that account does not exist.
what is the problem ?


An account is only valid on Solana if it meets the threshold of being rent exempt.
Rent is SOL in an account for validators to recognise and keep it in state.
To do this, sent some SOL to your address.
